# Log in multi domain by single login

Tags: php

How to log in one time and can use multiple domain
example : Google account can use http://google.com, http://youtube.com
by single login

[Server side PHP]

Comment: How does your side look like and how does your code work? Without any input from you we can't help you at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one database for two domains. Save in database info about user and read in antoher page.